# I m trying to add additional parameter in fulfillBasicOrder but it gives me error

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, assembly

When I add additional parameter in fulfillBasicOrder it gives me error of **InvalidBasicOrderParameterEncoding**

Please help me out how can I add additional parameter in this function as I have less understanding of assembly lang.

Comment: Can you share the modifications and the exact error generated?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I solved this issue by changing the pointers location.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing the pointers location.

```
    uint256 constant BasicOrder_additionalRecipients_length_cdPtr = 0x284; // 0x264
    uint256 constant BasicOrder_additionalRecipients_head_cdPtr = 0x224;
    uint256 constant BasicOrder_additionalRecipients_head_ptr = 0x260; // 0x240
    uint256 constant BasicOrder_totalOriginalAdditionalRecipients_cdPtr = 0x204;
    uint256 constant BasicOrder_additionalRecipients_data_cdPtr = 0x2a4; //0x304; // 0x284
```